# Why can't I pass my Object into session created in Webservice

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

Why can't I pass my Object into session created in Webservice?

```
[WebMethod]
public void UpdatedData(string CountryName, string CountryCode,
                        string City, string RegionCode, string RegionName) 
{            
    Chat ch = new Chat();
    ch.CountryName = CountryName;
    ch.CountryCode = CountryCode;
    ch.City = City;
    ch.RegionCode = RegionCode;
    ch.RegionName = RegionName;
    Session["Chat"] = ch;  //object Refrence not set to instance of an object
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 [ WebMethod(Description="Per session Hit Counter",EnableSession=true)]
public void UpdatedData(string CountryName, string CountryCode, string City, string RegionCode, string RegionName) 
{
Chat ch = new Chat(); 
ch.CountryName = CountryName; 
ch.CountryCode = CountryCode; 
ch.City = City; ch.RegionCode = RegionCode; 
ch.RegionName = RegionName; 
Session["Chat"] = ch;
}
```

Comment: Now How can i use this session on my Web Page its comming null every time

Answer (score 3):

Please put below code above your above method :

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod(EnableSession=true)]
```

Comment: Thankx but now i can't use this session in my application any help

Comment: Why please explain your problem

Comment: Im not a dummy profile n i hav liked ur comment as well @mahu can u tell me how do i use this session now as its coming null when im using it